# Using a variable as a template parameter, or alternate suggestions

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I’m extending a file parser for specific kinds of files. These files contain a limited number of known “chunks” where each chunk is represented as a struct in code. This is implemented using template specialization so that it remains type safe. Here’s an overview of how it’s all set up currently:

```
namespace fcc {
    enum FileTypes {
        ASND = 'ASND',
        // ... and so on
    };

    enum ChunkTypes {
        peak = 'peak',
        wvfm = 'wvfm',
        // ... and so on
    };
}


// Type is typedef'd to void to give compile-time error for invalid chunks
template <uint32 TFileType, uint32 TChunkType>
struct ChunkFactory {
    typedef void Type;
};


template <uint32 TFileType>
class BinaryFile {
    BinaryFile(void *data, size_t size);
    // ...
    template <uint32 TId>
    std::shared_ptr<typename ChunkFactory<TFileType,TChunkType>::Type> chunk() const {
        uint32 size;
        const byte* data = getChunk(TChunkType, size);

        if (data) { return std::make_shared<typename ChunkFactory<TFileType,TChunkType>::Type>(data, size); }
        else { return nullptr; }
    }
    // ...
}

// for each chunk that needs to be parsed into struct, i specialize the type
struct AudioPeakData {
    AudioPeakData(const byte* data, uint32 size);
    // ...
};
struct WaveformData {
    WaveformData(const byte* data, uint32 size);
    // ...
};
template<> struct ChunkFactory<fcc::ASND,fcc::peak> { typedef AudioPeakData Type; };
template<> struct ChunkFactory<fcc::ASND,fcc::wvfm> { typedef WaveformData Type; };
```

This allows me to do the following:

```
BinaryFile<Audio> file(fileBuffer, fileSize);
auto peakChunk = file.chunk<fcc::peak>();
auto wvfmChunk = file.chunk<fcc::wvfm>();
```

=========================================================================

The problem is that I now have to implement a way to parse versioned structures. So, for example, for audio peak data there is multiple versions of the struct that each holds different fields. Like I have here:

```
struct AudioPeakDataV1 {
    AudioPeakDataV1(const byte* data, uint32 size);

    int field1;
    string field2;
    vector<int> field3;
    // ...
};

struct AudioPeakDataV2 {
    AudioPeakDataV2(const byte* data, uint32 size);

    int field1;
    int field2;
    byte field3;
    // ...
};
```

I’m not incredibly experienced at c++ template programming, and so I initially thought I could pass in a version as a template parameter, like so:

```
template <uint32 TFileType, uint32 TChunkType, uint32 TVersion>
struct ChunkFactory {
    typedef void Type;
};
template<> struct ChunkFactory<fcc::ASND,fcc::peak,1> { typedef AudioPeakDataV1 Type; };
template<> struct ChunkFactory<fcc::ASND,fcc::peak,2> { typedef AudioPeakDataV2 Type; };

template <uint32 TFileType>
class BinaryFile {
    template <uint32 TId>
    std::shared_ptr<typename ChunkFactory<TFileType,TChunkType>::Type> chunk() const {
        uint32 size;
        uint32 version;
        const byte* data = getChunk(TChunkType, size, version);

        // version is not known at compile time, so can't pass it in template parameter.
        if (data) { return std::make_shared<typename ChunkFactory<TFileType,TChunkType,version>::Type>(data, size); }
        else { return nullptr; }
    }
    // ...
}
```

I’m looking for some tips on the best way to set this up. I’m considering Boost.MPL as I read on here that you with it you can use variables as template parameters, but as I’m inexperienced in template programming it’s quite overwhelming and I can’t figure out how to get it to do what I need done here.

I hope I’ve explained things clearly enough so someone might be able to guide me in the right direction.

Comment: so basically you want a versionized IO system. I would let the `WaveformData` read and react to the version number

Comment: I recommend getting yourself out of this template spaghetti rather than piling it up any higher.  The [strategy pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/889/Applying-Strategy-Pattern-in-C-Applications) is a much better choice for this type of problem, and you will only take a small type safety hit if done correctly.

Comment: @WorldSEnder I considered that, but it requires a revamp of the entire system, and as I mentioned I'm attempting to extend this one.

Comment: @qexyn Could you expand on this a little bit? This would probably also require me to change the whole structure, but I could explore it. If it seems suitable, I could accept as an answer.